# How do I inject fake into DI container?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to inject fakes into DI container, and I would expect them to be used instead of ones specified in Startup.
I tried this

```
var topicWriterFake = A.Fake<IServiceBusTopicWriter>();
A.CallTo(() => topicWriterFake.Write(A<string>.Ignored, A<string>.Ignored))
                    .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);

var webHostBuilder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>();   

webHostBuilder.ConfigureServices(sc => sc.AddScoped(p => topicWriterFake));

var serviceProvider = new DependencyResolver(_webHostBuilder.Build());

var sut = serviceProvider.GetService<IStripeService>();
```

IStripeService has dependency on IServiceBusTopicWriter. When above line resolves IStripeService it still uses instance that is wired up in Startup rather than the one provided through ConfigureServices method in the test. Any ideas if this is doable?

Comment: Why not instead instantiate the service you are trying to test with the fakes passed into the constructor?

Comment: @PmanAce: Because that makes test fragile and it does not mimic what code in prod is doing.

Answer (score 0):

When using a web host builder with [`WebHostBuilder.ConfigureServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilder.configureservices?view=aspnetcore-2.1), the services that are configured on the builder are being registered at a very specific time when the web host is being built. However, the `ConfigureServices` within your `Startup` class is called **after that**.

So while you can use `ConfigureServices` on the builder to add services to your web host, the `Startup` still allows you to overwrite everything. This is usually a good thing but of course will not help you when you want to integration test your application.

I would suggest you to use the new [`WebApplicationFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to author your integration tests. It already comes with a lot of utilities that help you with your [integration tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

One of the things the factory allows you to do is to [inject mock services for testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#inject-mock-services). You can use the [`ConfigureTestServices` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.testhost.webhostbuilderextensions.configuretestservices?view=aspnetcore-2.1) on the web host builder for that.

Under the hoods, the web application factory uses [`IStartupConfigureServicesFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.internal.istartupconfigureservicesfilter?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to make this work. You can register implementations of that with your application and their [`ConfigureServices` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.internal.istartupconfigureservicesfilter.configureservices?view=aspnetcore-2.1) will run to set up the service configuration pipeline for the `Startup` type. So you can register multiple configuration actions and have them run explicitly at the end.

So if for some reason you cannot or don’t want to use the web application factory (although it makes integration testing a lot easier), you can still make this work explicitly like this:

```
var webHostBuilder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IStartupConfigureServicesFilter>(new MockInjectorFilter(s =>
        {
            s.AddScoped(p => topicWriterFake);
        });
    });
```

```
public class MockInjectorFilter : IStartupConfigureServicesFilter
{
    private readonly Action<IServiceCollection> _configureServices;

    public ConfigureTestServicesStartupConfigureServicesFilter(Action<IServiceCollection> configureServices)
        => _configureServices = configureServices ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configureServices));

    public Action<IServiceCollection> ConfigureServices(Action<IServiceCollection> next)
        => serviceCollection =>
        {
            next(serviceCollection);
            _configureServices(serviceCollection);
        };
}
```